# How to convert a multidimensional String array (String[][])to a multidimensional double array (double[][]) by using java 8 stream?

Tags: java, lambda, stream

for example, convert a String[][]  {{"1","2"},{"3","4"},{"5","6"}} to a double[][] {{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0},{5.0,6.0}}.
I tried:

```
Arrays.stream(strArr).map(s ->
            Arrays.stream(s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray()).toArray();
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

To create `double[][]`, you need to use

```
double[][] result = Arrays.stream(input).map(s -> Arrays.stream(s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray()).toArray(double[][]::new);
```